# Troubleshoot for loop with arithmetic in shell

Tags: loops, shell, csv, printf

I'm trying to write a loop that pulls sequencing metrics from column 2 of a txt file (ending in full_results.txt) and writes everything into a combined tsv (ideally with headers as well, but I haven't been able to do that).

The below makes a tsv with all of the columns I want--but stopped looping. The loop was working before I added the last two columns, so I'm not sure if adding the fields with arithmetic changed anything. Let me know if there is a cleaner way to write this! Thanks for your input.

```
{
for i in *full_results.txt;
do
[ -d "$i" ] && continue
[ -s "$1" ] && continue
                total=$(awk ' $1=="NORMALIZED_READ_COUNT" { print $2 } ' $i)
                trimmed=$(awk ' $1=="RAW_FRAGMENT_TOTAL" { print $2 } ' $i)
                aligned=$(awk ' $1=="RAW_FRAGMENT_FILTERED" { print $2 } ' $i)
                molbin=$(awk ' $1=="AVERAGE_UNIQUE_DNA_READS_PER_GSP2" { print $2 } ' $i)
                startsite=$(awk ' $1=="AVERAGE_UNIQUE_DNA_START_SITES_PER_GSP2" { print $2 } ' $i)
                dedup=$(awk ' $1=="ON_TARGET_DEDUPLICATION_RATIO" { print $2 } ' $i)
                printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$i" $total $trimmed $aligned $molbin $startsite $dedup $((total - trimmed)) "$(( ( (total - trimmed) * 100) / total))"
done;
} > sequencing_metrics.tsv
```

Output:

> NR02_31_S31_merged_R1_001_full_results.txt    7095319 6207119 6206544 1224.43 391.65  2.74:1  888200  12

Intended output: the same as above but looped for all files in the folder

Comment: Note that `“` is not `"` -- only the latter works as a double quote character in shell.

Comment: Beyond that, have you considered rewriting your whole script in awk? Running a whole lot of tiny individual awk scripts is extremely inefficient, when you could just have one awk interpreter do the whole thing.

Comment: Anyhow -- if your code really is using `[ -d “$i“ ]` instead of `[ -d "$i" ]`, that's a true/concrete bug, because even if you have a directory named `my_full_results.txt`, you probably don't have one named `“my_full_results.txt“`, and because `“` isn't recognized by the shell as syntax it gets treated as part of the filename.

Comment: Beyond that -- any chance your code is running in a context with `set -e` set? That would make an early exit a lot easier to understand, because it means any command with a nonzero exit status would cause an early exit.

Comment: BTW, you can use `$(( ( (total - trimmed) * 100) / total))` -- you only need the double parens on the outside; once you're in an arithmetic context you just need a single paren for grouping.

Comment: ...another hint: Use `bash -x yourscript` to run the script in trace mode so you see the actual commands it's running, and can also see exactly where it stops.

Comment: Thanks for the notes! I corrected the " issue and will clean-up the parentheses. It still isn't looping but I will try to run it in trace mode

Comment: Great. BTW, if you want your trace to come with line numbers, you can enable that by setting the `PS4` variable; a lot of my scripts have a header that includes `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+'` so when they're run in xtrace mode the output includes filename and line numbers.